# In Winter's Heart and Crossroads of Twilight, what chapters can I skip?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time

*Winter's Heart* and *Crossroads of Twilight* are much too slow paced for my tastes, but I want to get through them so I can read final few, faster-paced entries in the series.

What chapters can I skip while still being be able to understand the overarching story, as well as later books in the series?

Please use spoiler tags!

---

For whatever it's worth: I previously stumbled upon a GameFAQs post (that I can no longer find the source of) which said that everything in *Crossroads of Twilight* could be skipped EXCEPT for the prologue, chapters 1-3, 5-9, and 22-29, and the epilogue. This sounds promising, but I'm not sure I want to trust a single, random internet comment.

Comment: This strikes me as pretty opinion-based, unless you can offer some criteria to narrow down what you're looking for, like particular plotlines or characters?

Comment: What chapters/plotlines can I skip while still being able to understand the rest of the books in the series? What chapters are not crucial to the overarching story?

Comment: Yeah, that's what you said originally.  That's why it's not easy to answer; some people have skipped entire books and enjoyed much of the finale (*raises hand*).  I'd rather you try to be more specific before votes to close start coming in.  Asking for "good bits" is pretty subjective, but you know that, which I assume is why you didn't trust the one bit you got from elsewhere.

Comment: I don’t know. This seems pretty similar to [tag:suggested-order] questions, which we allow on a similar basis. We’ve got a similar question about what one must have read in order to understand *Harry Potter and the Cursed Child*, too.

Comment: So the problem is that I haven't read the story yet, so I have no way of knowing what plot-lines I should or should not ignore. I have read elsewhere in many places that there are a couple of SUPER important events in both WH and CoT that make them impossible to skip (but that the events themselves would be spoilers). If you think that means this question is simply inappropriate on this site, so be it (although I obviously hope you won't!), but I'm not sure how to be more detailed.

Comment: asking for plot driven chapters probably are on topic

Comment: the trick for reading these books is to learn to skim

Comment: @Himarm I'm using audiobooks though. :(

Comment: @Wowfunhappy Fair enough. We'll see who else chimes in.

Comment: @Wowfunhappy You might look into [the Wheel of Time Encyclopedia](http://www.encyclopaedia-wot.org/) which has good, annotated summaries of chapters of all the books (except the last).  Unless, of course, it's too late.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is pretty tough to be objective about. Everyone has their own preferences as to what is important (or enjoyable) to read. As a result, I've attempted to provide very general statements for each book about what you'll be reading (or listening to in your case) and what you'll be skipping.

As a more general note: If you're REALLY pressed for time, the absolute minimum to read would be: The prologue and Ch35 of Winter's Heart, and you can skip Crossroads of Twilight entirely except for the epilogue.

---

**Winter's Heart:**

*Read ->* Prologue, Chapters 11-19, 22, 25, 28-35.

In very general terms, this gets you: [minimal spoilers below]

> Some key info that sets the tone of the book, almost all of the chapters to do directly with Rand, almost all the chapters about Mat, and a very important event for the series as a whole.

You will miss out on: [minimal spoilers below]

> Perrin's story, Elayne's story, minor flavor chapters from other points of view.

---

**Crossroads of Twilight:**

The recommended chapters you found are not bad, but I would take them a step further.

*Read ->* Prologue, Ch1-4, Ch16-20 (these are fairly tedious, but plot important), Ch21-24, Ch28-30 and the Epilogue.

This gets you [minor spoilers]:

> Mat's continuing story, Egwene and the rebel Aes Sedai, Ongoing stories regarding the major event of Winter's Heart, Enough interstitial bits to keep everything tied together. These chapters serve to set the stage for the next two books.

You skip [minor spoilers]:

> Perrin's chapters again, Elayne's chapters

---

For the sake of other people looking to try to answer this, here is my logic:
**[Beware that this will have FULL SPOILERS]**

> Perrin's whole "saving Faile" plotline is probably the most slowly paced part of both of these books and fails to progress in any significant way throughout. Just skipping his chapters saves a lot of time. It also ends up being pretty unimportant in the long run. Elayne's politics are probably the second most tedious aspect of the two books and the end result of the whole Andor subplot is fairly moot in the long run. Mat's story with Tuon is typically considered very entertaining, though there might be some way to minimize the number of chapters devoted to it (I just included them all). The Rebel Aes Sedai also tend to have boring chapters, but Egwene's rise to the control of the White Tower is a pretty big deal... so I kept them in. Overall the most important bits in my mind are Rand's madness and cleansing of Saidin, some evil characters getting offed (Forsaken for the most part), and the change in how the rebel Aes Sedai think about and do things. Knife of Dreams and Sandersons novels focus for the most part on Rand, Egwene and Mat, basically wrapping up the dull Perrin and Elayne bits in short order.

Comment: Thanks, I *really* appreciate this. I've made a note to come back and accept this once I actually finish reading the series (assuming I can if the question is on hold?)

Comment: Years later, I finished whole series, and reading these chapters worked pretty well! If I could change anything, I think I'd take out chapters 16 through 17 or 18 in CoT, as while Egwane's plotline was important, those chapters did little to advance it. Also, there were sections in Winter Heart's last chapter from the point of view of characters I did not recognize at all--but maybe that's unavoidable? The plot itself never became difficult to follow.